# Is word substitution invertible?

Tags: semigroups, combinatorics-on-words

Here is the problem. Let us say we have a word made up of two letters, for example, $ABBBA$. Say I enforce the substitution $A\to AB$ to get the word $ABBBBAB$. Is it always the case that if I know the final word and the substitution, I can blindly turn $AB\to A$ one by one from left to right and get the original word? Clearly, you can create the substitution word "accidentally":

For example:
$ABA$ enforce $A\to ABA$ then we get $ABABABA$, notice here we created another $ABA$, doing reverse substitution still works though. The issue is, what if we create the substitution word in the beginning? Then I think we will not go back to the original. I do not think that is possible, but was wondering if anyone could confirm my suspicion.

Comment: If you find a single word with two possible original words, you are done. Should not be that difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \{a, b\}$ and let $u, v \in A^*$. A well-known result (see for instance [1, Chapter 1]) states that the following conditions are equivalent:

1. the monoid generated by $u$ and $v$ is not free,
2. $uv = vu$,
3. $u = w^p$ and $v = w^q$ for some $w \in A^*$ and some $p, q \geqslant 0$.

It follows that the monoid morphism $f: A^* \to A^*$ defined by $f(a) = u$ and $f(b) = v$ is injective if and only if $uv \not= vu$.

EDIT. For instance, if $f(a) = ab$ and $f(b) = b$, then $f$ is injective since $(ab)a = aba \not= aab = a(ab)$. If $f(a) = b^n$ and $f(b) = b$, then $f$ is not injective since $b^nb = bb^n$ (or directly since $f(a) = f(b^n)$.

[1] Lothaire, M. Combinatorics on words. Corrected reprint of the 1983 original, with a new preface by Perrin. Cambridge Mathematical Library. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1997. xviii +238 pp. ISBN: 0-521-59924-5

Comment: Just to fully understand then. Since I am only doing a single substitution say $A->AB$ all I have to worry about is that the substitution does not commute with $B$ correct? But that is only the case when the substitution is $A->B^n$ is that correct?

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your comment.